# Best way to handle 2+ template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates

Say I have a templated function in the following form:

```
template<bool a, bool b, bool c>
void foo(){
   if(a) printf("I do something when a is true!\n");
   if(b) printf("I do something when b is true!\n");
   if(c) printf("I do something when c is true!\n");
}
```

Now I have this function that can be compile time specialized for each of the 8 possibles cases (a = b = c = true, a=b=true c=false, etc etc).

I would like to call this function with values of a, b and c obtained on run time.

If the template had only one parameter I could do:

```
void caller(bool a){
   if(a) foo<true>();
   else  foo<false>();
}
```

But what if you have 2+ parameters? You cannot just do:

```
void caller(bool a, bool b, bool c){
   foo<a,b,c>();
}
```

And the casuistic madness if you do it with if-else/switch is undesirable.
I would like for the compiler to compile the 8 versions of foo and just call

```
foo<a,b,c>()
```

An equivalent situation can be made if instead bool I have:

```
template<int a>
void foo(){
   printf("%d", a);
}
```

Say that I know that a can vary between 0 and, i.e, 32.
I would like to do something like:

```
void caller(int a){
   if(a<=32 && a>0) foo<a>();
   else printf("ERROR!/n");
}
```

What would be the best way to handle these kind of situations?

Comment: Better use constexpr function not template. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr

Comment: ...wouldn't the simplest way be to make each `if` case in the original function its own bool-templated function, then call them from the compile-time and run-time versions of the three template parameter function? I'm assuming your implementations of the various functions aren't constexpr...

Comment: `a,b,c` must be known compile-time for `foo<a,b,c>()` to work

Comment: Make foo a non-templated function? What are you really trying to achieve? How did you came to the point where you need to inject run-time values into compile-time constants?

Comment: You're mixing runtime parameters with compile-time parameters and diving into `constexpr` will only make things worse if you don't clear the former out first

Comment: @YSC Of course this is an overly simplified example. In my application this translates to a very critical cuda kernel that I want to specialize depending of several flags or integers. I have seen that in this case actually including the conditionals in the function (the non-templated version as you say) has a great performance impact.

Comment: @jaggedSpire In the example function "foo" sure, but in the real world "foo" is not that trivial of a function... Anyway, regardless of "foo", I believe the question is clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But what if you have 2+ parameters? You cannot just do:

You can use *variadic templates*, recursion, higher-order functions and `std::integral_constant`:

```
template <typename TF>
auto with_bool_constant(TF xf)
{
    return xf();
};

template <typename TF, typename T, typename... Ts>
auto with_bool_constant(TF xf, T x, Ts... xs)
{
    if(x) 
        return with_bool_constant([&](auto... ys)
                                  { xf(std::integral_constant<bool, true>{}, ys...); }, 
                                  xs...);
    else 
        return with_bool_constant([&](auto... ys)
                                  { xf(std::integral_constant<bool, false>{}, ys...); }, 
                                  xs...);
};
```

Usage:

```
template <bool a, bool b, bool c>
void f() 
{ 
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << a << " " << b << " " << c << "\n"; 
}

int main()
{
    auto f_wrapper = [](auto a, auto b, auto c)
    {
        return f<a, b, c>();
    };

    with_bool_constant(f_wrapper, true, false, true);
}
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/i8WP9V5AwUzvjwf5)

---

> Say that I know that a can vary between 0 and, i.e, 32. I would like to do something like:

You can use `boost::hana::make_range` to generate a `0...32` compile-time range *(the bounds must be known at compile time)*. You can then use `boost::hana::for_each` or a similar compile-time iteration construct to convert a runtime value to `std::integral_constant<int, X>` and apply a similar technique to the one I posted above.

Answer (score 2):

You've got the right idea, you just have to do it quasirecursively for every parameter:

```
#include <cstdio>

template <bool a, bool b, bool c>
void foo() {
     if(a) printf("I do something when a is true!\n");
     if(b) printf("I do something when b is true!\n");
     if(c) printf("I do something when c is true!\n");
}

template <bool... bs>
void caller() {
    foo<bs...>();
}

template <bool... cbs, typename... RBS>
void caller(bool rb0, RBS... rbs) {
    if (rb0) {
        caller<cbs..., true>(rbs...);
    } else {
        caller<cbs..., false>(rbs...);
    }
}

int main() {
     caller(true, false, true);
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity - could you confirm or deny my suspicion that compiling `caller(a,b,c)` causes instantiation of all possible variants of `foo()` ?

Comment: @Arkadiy yes, and that is going to be true for any such mapping from compile-time to run-time values.